# which is the best way to store small amount of permanent data in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have to store uploaded file version and previous file name and version permanently, moreover, I need to update and retrieve that information, but I'm not using any databases for this application. Is it possible to keep data in Web.Config file and able to update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't keep it in Web.Config. Updating web.config would cause application pool to recycle, instead store it in some XML file if you want to. Not really sure why you want to avoid database for this purpose but you can even store it in a file based database like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Comment: its small application which is used to upload applications and download it. hence its not using any databases, but I want to keep previous file versions and file names.

Comment: @Delphian, Keep them in a separate XML file, or even TEXT file, what ever floats your boat :), but not in `web.config`.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the data in the web.config if you want to, but i wouldn't really recommend it.
But If its a small app and don't really care about user's session state / application pool, then i don't see why not.

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then you can retrieve the data as follow

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Version"]
```

**However** you can create your own **xml** file then retrieve it in your code as follow

xml

```
<ApplicationConfig>
    <Version>2.0.0.0</Version>
</ApplicationConfig>
```

Then in your code

```
if (File.Exists(configFile))
{
    var xml = XDocument.Load(configFile);
            if (xml.Root != null)
            {
                var version = xml.Root.Elements("ApplicationConfig").Elements("Version").Value
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing the data in file is one way to go. There are just a few things to be aware of:

1. Use App_Data subfolder but also make sure that your application pool identity has write permissions there.
2. Use a thread-safe approach for writing and reading that file (such as a global lock).

Alternatively you could write the value in the [registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. This approach would not require setting permissions on the file system which sometime is not possible.

Just in case the information you store is unique to the user you might want to use [ASP.NET Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Since you don't want to use database you can use a [custom provider](http://aspnetxmlproviders.codeplex.com/) that stores the data in XML files.